# Entity framework add's new record in one-to-one relation while object has an ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to c# and I have a basic problem with saving/updating data.
With two classes :

```
public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegisteredDate { get; set; }

 public class Task
    {
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public User DeclaredBy { get; set; }

    }
```

I'm trying to save a task object (new or updated) with `DeclaredBy` field set

```
dbContext.Tasks.AddOrUpdate(task);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

User set in `DeclaredBy` field has an ID, but after executing `SaveChanges()` a new record of User appears in DB.

Comment: Show us the code that you are using to save the record. Also show us the database table definition for User and Task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how EF works, if you add entity with other related entity then both will be stored in DB. If you want to store only one then you need to set other navigation properties to null and only set foreign key id, which currently you don't have, you should add property:

```
public int DeclatedById { get; set; }
```

Btw. this is very common problem and a lot of projects has duplicate values in db.

Maybe I should add that this will happen only if entity wasn't traced by EF context and was attached to it.